# Hiding ASP file name from HTML

Tags: html, asp-classic

I have an HTML form:

```
<form id="form" action="Secret.asp" method="POST">
```

This form sends data from my website visitor to a database.

I want to hide it so that whoever sees my HTML will not be able to send data to my ASP file.

Or maybe there is another way to block an ASP file from anyone but the HTML file?

Comment: If you're worried about a comments page or a forum being spammed then your only real option is to use a CAPTCHA, which is why you see so many of them these days.  If you're worried about SQL injection attacks then you need to use range protection.  Google should give you plenty of examples

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose you could set up a default document on a virtual directory, and set the action to that. Then your user wouldn't see the page name, but the form data would still get posted.

The bigger question is... why do you want to do this? If it's a matter of security through obscurity, this is the wrong approach. Whatever page receives the form data should not trust it at all, and should sanitize anything going into a database anyway.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this makes things much clearer.
So, how do I make a classic ASP file to only accept data from the html form?

Comment: @Zephram you can check the referer string, but that can be spoofed as well.

Answer (score 2):

No.

If you want browsers to be able to send data to a URL, then you have to tell them what that URL is.

Anything you tell a browser, you tell to the user in control of that browser.

Answer (score 0):

No matter what you do, anyone can see their own HTTP requests going out to your server.

If you press F12 on Chrome or Firefox you can see your incoming and outgoing traffic, so it's useless to try and do anything about it.

If you want to secure something, that's not the way to go about it.